# Time to failure variable based off start and end timestamps in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have two data sets. Data set 1 contains time stamps of 15 minute intervals starting at *2009-08-18 18:15:00* and ending 2012-11-09 *22:30:00* with measurements taken at those times. Data set 2 has start and end time stamps for faults occurring in a factory. There are 6 faults and these faults' start and end times are also 15 min intervals, yet can last longer than 1 interval. They also all fall somewhere between *2009-08-18 18:15:00* and *2012-11-09 22:30:00* as well. I am trying to create a time to failure variable for the faults, where *-i* would indicate the next fault is *i* intervals (which are 15 mins) away and *i* would indicate the fault started *i* intervals ago. For example,

```
    DataSet1
    Timestamp               Sensor 1
    2009-09-04 10:00:00     30
    2009-09-04 10:30:00     40
    2009-09-04 10:45:00     33
    2009-09-04 11:00:00     23
    2009-09-04 11:15:00     24
    2009-09-04 11:30:00     42

    DataSet 2
    Start Time            End Time     Fault Type
    09/04/09 10:45  9/4/2009 11:15      1
    09/04/09 21:45  9/4/2009 22:00      1
    09/04/09 23:00  9/4/2009 23:15      1
    09/05/09 10:45  9/5/2009 11:15      1
    09/05/09 21:30  9/5/2009 23:15      1
    09/08/09 10:45  9/8/2009 12:30      1
```

So what I want to end up with is the following time to failure variable (TTF1) and then repeat the process for faults 2-6

```
    Timestamp               Sensor 1     TTF1
    2009-09-04 10:00:00     30           -3
    2009-09-04 10:30:00     40           -1
    2009-09-04 10:45:00     33            0
    2009-09-04 11:00:00     23            1
    2009-09-04 11:15:00     24            2
    2009-09-04 11:30:00     42           -41
```

I know I can use the sqldf function to separate out each fault type, but I have no clue where to begin to even create counting the time to fault variable. I'm very stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you want `difftime()`

Comment: I would avoid using `sqldf` in R. It is known to take longer to run than other functions. Look at `which` and `data.table`.

Comment: I can give an even more custom solution for you if you can create a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Basically it means that I can copy code from your question, run it, and then I'll have the data sets I need to produce the result you want based on an example of that result which you've entered in the question. However my existing answer may hopefully be sufficient as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `difftime()` function from base R to get the time difference between these 2 timestamps:

```
(z <- Sys.time() - 3600)
Sys.time() - z                # just over 3600 seconds.
as.difftime(c("0:3:20", "11:23:15"))
as.difftime(c("3:20", "23:15", "2:"), format = "%H:%M") # 3rd gives NA
(z <- as.difftime(c(0,30,60), units = "mins"))
as.numeric(z, units = "secs")
as.numeric(z, units = "hours")
format(z)
```

I would recommend set `units = "mins"`. You can convert the `class` to `character`, strip out any non-numeric data with `gsub`, then change the class with `as.numeric`. Finally just divide by 15 to get the 15-minute time units you want. You can use `floor` to round the result if needed.

Comment: I think my issue however, isn't that I just want how many intervals between the start and end time; I want to be able to use my Timestamp column (which has every 15 minute interval)  to count down the intervals left until a fault starts, then once it starts count how many until it ends, then  again start counting until one starts. So basically I think it would involve doing some kind of ifelse statement but with difftime. But I have no idea where to begin. Sorry, if I'm not being very clear.

Comment: @mq42 Oh ok, I think I get it now. Is there any way that you can `dput` that data so that I can read it in and try to use it for an example solution?

Comment: structure(list(Timestamp = structure(1:5, .Label = c("    2009-09-04 10:30:00", 
"    2009-09-04 10:45:00", "    2009-09-04 11:00:00", "    2009-09-04 11:15:00", 
"    2009-09-04 11:30:00"), class = "factor"), Sensor.1 = c(30L, 
40L, 33L, 23L, 24L)), .Names = c("Timestamp", "Sensor.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Comment: First one is for dput(Dataset1). Here is dput(Dataset2)
structure(list(Start.Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("09/04/09 10:45", 
"09/04/09 21:45", "09/04/09 23:00", "09/05/09 10:45", "09/05/09 21:30", 
"09/08/09 10:45"), class = "factor"), End.Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("9/4/2009 11:15", 
"9/4/2009 22:00", "9/4/2009 23:15", "9/5/2009 11:15", "9/5/2009 23:15", 
"9/8/2009 12:30"), class = "factor"), Fault.Type = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Start.Time", "End.Time", "Fault.Type"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Comment: Finally here is the dataset I'm hoping to get if you need it: dput(TargetDataset)
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(1:5, .Label = c("    2009-09-04 10:30:00", 
"    2009-09-04 10:45:00", "    2009-09-04 11:00:00", "    2009-09-04 11:15:00", 
"    2009-09-04 11:30:00"), class = "factor"), Sensor.1 = c(30L, 
40L, 33L, 23L, 24L), TTF1 = c(-1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, -41L)), .Names = c("Timestamp", 
"Sensor.1", "TTF1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Comment: @mq42 Thanks, I will come back to it this evening

Comment: Just wondering if you had any more ideas for this problem. Thanks.